# Sum values in matrix with if statement

Tags: r

I have the hourly values of the generator that works (1) or does not work (0) in the whole year. Now I need to calculate the produced electricity if I know that the generation capacity in one hour is 40GW. So sum all the hours when the generator is on and subtract the hours when is of and multiply the result with 40. I just don't know if there is any function in R to do this fast.

```
ccmix
  [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1272.819    1
[2,] 1289.226    0
[3,] 5308.784    1
[4,] 5338.036    0
[5,] 5797.671    1
[6,] 5859.749    0
[7,] 8760.000    1
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Just the final number of produced electricity in one year

Comment: You can try `40*(sum(ccmix[,1][!!ccmix[,2]])- sum(ccmix[,1][!ccmix[,2]]))`

Comment: Perfect it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second column is binary.  So one way would be to change it to logical vector, subset the values that correspond to 'ON' and 'OFF' (i.e. 1 and 0), get the difference of the `sum` of both and multiply with 40.

```
 40*(sum(ccmix[,1][!!ccmix[,2]]) - sum(ccmix[,1][!ccmix[,2]]))
```

The negate function (`!`) converts 0 to TRUE and 1 to FALSE.  If we do the double negate (`!!`), 1 becomes TRUE and 0 as FALSE.  Instead of the negation, we can wrap with `as.logical` to get 1 converted to TRUE, 0 to FALSE.